# SQL Server looping execution takes too much time

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, mssql-jdbc

I have a table `#TrackPlayedInformation` upon which I am looping. Sample data of `#TrackPlayedInformation` is as follows:

```
   ProfileTrackTimeId   JukeBoxTrackId  ProfileId   EndTime                    SessionId    StartTime
         14                  52              33     2014-08-16 05:47:19.410    23424234   2014-08-16 05:45:19.410
         15                  51              33     2014-11-16 05:47:19.410    23424234   2014-08-16 05:45:19.410
```

I am looping through `#TrackPlayedInformation` and splits the time interval between start time and end time on each minute. New time is inserted on a physical table `TempGraph`

Structure of TempGraph is

```
TempGraphId   AirTime                    AirCount
170390        2014-08-16 05:46:19.410       0
170391        2014-08-16 05:47:19.410       0
```

While inserting to `TempGraph` if not exists is checked, if exists it updates aircount incremented by 1 else inserted as new entry.

The query execution takes about 20 minutes to complete id the date interval is about 3 month. Is there any faster way to achieve the result?

My workout query is as follows:

```
USE [SocialMob]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[pDeleteTempGraph]    Script Date: 01/02/2015 09:00:32 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pDeleteTempGraph]

AS
BEGIN
print('start')
declare @UserId int
declare @ProfileTrackTimeId int
set @UserId=1048
drop table #TrackPlayedInformation
delete from TempGraph
declare @loopCount int
declare @StartTime datetime
declare @LastDate datetime
declare @tempCount int
declare @EndTime datetime
declare @SaveTime datetime
declare @checkDate datetime
declare @countCheck int

--querying input--
--drop table #TrackPlayedInformation
--declare @UserId int
--set @UserId=33
SELECT ProfileTrackTimeId,ProfileTrackTime.JukeBoxTrackId,ProfileId,EndTime,SessionId,StartTime into #TrackPlayedInformation
 FROM ProfileTrackTime  LEFT JOIN
(SELECT JukeBoxTrackId FROM JukeBoxTrack INNER JOIN 
Album ON JukeBoxTrack.AlbumId=Album.AlbumId WHERE Album.UserId=@UserId) as AllTrackId 
ON ProfileTrackTime.JukeBoxTrackId=AllTrackId.JukeBoxTrackId


set @loopCount=0
declare @count as int
select @count=COUNT(ProfileTrackTimeId) from #TrackPlayedInformation
set @LastDate=GETDATE()--storing current datetime
print('looping starts')
while @loopCount<@count
begin
    select @StartTime=StartTime from #TrackPlayedInformation
    select @EndTime=EndTime from #TrackPlayedInformation
    select @ProfileTrackTimeId=ProfileTrackTimeId from #TrackPlayedInformation

    --select @checkDate=AirTime from TempGraph 
        while @StartTime<=@EndTime
        begin
            set @StartTime=DATEADD(minute,1,@StartTime)

            --checking for duplication
            --SELECT @countCheck= count(TempGraphId) FROM TempGraph WHERE AirTime=@StartTime
            --select @countCheck
            --if (@countCheck<1)
            if not exists(select top 1 TempGraphId from TempGraph where AirTime=@StartTime)
            begin
                --print('inserting')
                insert TempGraph (AirTime,AirCount) values(@StartTime,0)
            end
            else
            begin
                --print('updating')
                update TempGraph set AirCount=AirCount+1 where AirTime=@StartTime
            end
            set @LastDate=@StartTime 
        end

        set @LastDate=DATEADD(MINUTE,1,@LastDate);
    --deleting row from #TrackPlayedInformation
        --print('deleting')
        delete from #TrackPlayedInformation where ProfileTrackTimeId=@ProfileTrackTimeId
        set @loopCount=@loopCount+1 --incrementing looping condition
end

begin
    insert TempGraph (AirTime,AirCount) values(@LastDate,0)
end

begin
    declare @nowdate datetime
    set @nowdate=GETDATE()
    insert TempGraph (AirTime,AirCount) values(@nowdate,0)
end

    select * from TempGraph;
    delete from TempGraph;
END
```

I am trying to split a time interval by minute for eg- consider date 2014 01 01 5.40 as start time and 2014 01 01 5.50 as end time.i need to entry in TempGraph as 2014 01 01 5.41, 2014 01 01 5.42, 2014 01 01 5.43 .....upto 2014 01 01 5.50

Comment: what is the use last two inserts (ie) `@LastDate` and `@nowdate`.

Comment: the --@LastDate is used to insert the last entry and --@nowdate is used to insert a entry on current datetime

Comment: *i am trying to split a time interval by minute for eg- consider date 2014 01 01 5.40 as start time and 2014 01 01 5.50 as end time* Well just use a recursive cte to generate a sequence of numbers (minutes) between 0 and 10 and then `DATEADD` them to your starting time. http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/t-sql-using-common-table-expressions-cte-to-generate-sequences/

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. Nevertheless, loops in SQL should be avoided if possible.

You might consider an `UPDATE` statement similar to:

```
UPDATE TempGraph
SET    AirCount = AirCount + 1
WHERE  AirTime BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime
```

followed by something that inserts records for the "missing" times. Without more information on the purpose of this code, it is difficult to provide more help.

Comment: i am trying to split a time interval by minute for eg- consider date 2014 01 01 5.40 as start time and 2014 01 01 5.50 as end time.i need to entry in TempGraph as 2014 01 01 5.41,  2014 01 01 5.42,  2014 01 01 5.43 .....upto    2014 01 01 5.50

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually understand what you are trying to do. The following may help you

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP
FROM
(
SELECT 14 ProfileTrackTimeId,'2014-08-16 05:47:19.410' StartTime,   '2014-08-16 05:50:19.410' EndTime
UNION ALL
SELECT 14 ProfileTrackTimeId,'2014-08-16 10:20:19.410' StartTime,   '2014-08-16 10:23:19.410' EndTime
UNION ALL
SELECT 20 ProfileTrackTimeId,'2014-08-17 08:10:19.410' StartTime,   '2014-08-17 08:12:19.410' EndTime
UNION ALL
SELECT 20 ProfileTrackTimeId,'2014-08-18 13:59:19.410' StartTime,   '2014-08-18 14:02:19.410' EndTime
)TAB
```

Now you will get every date with minute between `starttime` and `endtime` for every `ProfileTrackTimeId`

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT ProfileTrackTimeId,CAST(StartTime AS DATETIME) FDATES,
   CAST(EndTime AS DATETIME) TDATES
   FROM #TEMP  
   UNION ALL
   SELECT T.ProfileTrackTimeId,DATEADD(MINUTE,1,FDATES),TDATES 
   FROM #TEMP T
   JOIN CTE ON CTE.ProfileTrackTimeId = T.ProfileTrackTimeId
   WHERE FDATES < TDATES
)
SELECT DISTINCT ProfileTrackTimeId,FDATES 
FROM CTE
ORDER BY ProfileTrackTimeId,FDATES
OPTION (MaxRecursion 0)
```

Please let me know for any change.

Comment: +One Recursive CTE although you probably want to set `MAXRECURSION` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks  ta.speot.is. If forgot to give. Will update @ta.speot.is

Answer (score 0):

To create sequence between startTime and EndTime you can use pattern with the [nodes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) method. To perform insert and update operations you can use [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement. The following example show you how to do this.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[pDeleteTempGraph]
AS
BEGIN

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#seq') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #seq
    CREATE TABLE #seq(AirTime datetime, AirCount int)

    ;WITH cte AS
    (
     SELECT *, CAST(REPLICATE(CAST('<M></M>' AS varchar(MAX)),ISNULL(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, EndTime), 1)) AS xml) AS xmlCol
     FROM #TrackPlayedInformation t1
     ),cte2 AS
    (  
     SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY profileTrackTimeId ORDER BY StartTime), StartTime) AS AirTime
     FROM cte CROSS APPLY xmlCol.nodes ('/M') AS Split(M)
     )
     INSERT #seq
     SELECT AirTime, COUNT(*) AS AirCount
     FROM cte2
     GROUP BY AirTime

     MERGE TempGraph AS TARGET
     USING (           
            SELECT AirTime, AirCount
            FROM #seq           
            ) AS SOURCE ON TARGET.AirTime = SOURCE.AirTime
     WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET AirCount = TARGET.AirCount + SOURCE.AirCount
     WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
     INSERT(AirTime, AirCount)
     VALUES(SOURCE.AirTime, SOURCE.AirCount);

     SELECT *
     FROM TempGraph

     DELETE FROM TempGraph

END
```

But maybe MERGE statement is excessive in your particular case and will be enough the table #seq. Anyway if you have an additional UPSERT logic it will be good idea to do it with MERGE statement.